# .then() clause is not executed

Tags: javascript, fetch

i am a new proggraming student and now i am traying to get a response to a request from an api (PokeAPI), but when i do the request the .then clauses are not executed. Can you please help me, thanks.

```
'use strict'
let form = document.querySelector('#formulario')
form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    let nombrePokemon = form.pokemon.value;
    let urlCompleta = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + nombrePokemon;
    //alert(urlCompleta);
    fetch(urlCompleta)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
        let elemento = document.querySelector('#element')
        elemento.innerHTML = `
        <p>${data.name}</p>
        <p>${data.order}</p>
        <img src='${data.sprites.front_default}'/>
        `
        console.log(data);   
    })
})
```

Comment: _is not executed_ and what is happening? can you post also the form you are submitting?

Comment: If the `then()` does not execute, that would lead to the suspicion that the request is failing.  check your network console

Comment: Trying the snippet here on S.O. and hard coding the value to '100', this logic works as written.  At least as far as the fetch is concerned.

Comment: Never forget a `.catch(console.error)` in the end. Although if that was the issue, you should have been getting an unhandled rejection warning in the console.

Comment: @Bergi Assuming that the OP has checked the console, and not just watching the browser waiting for the DOM change...

Comment: @FZs yeah. They are using `console.log(data)` though.

Comment: @Bergi I saw that, but I also saw *many* people who had a `console` method in their code without even knowing about the developer console. Not everyone writes the code that they have to work with...

Comment: Thanks  for your answers, yes i have checked the console and network i get a 200 response but no json in it. but if i check the final composed url on my browser is ok and contains the json.

Comment: Could it be possible to be a server problem/config and not my code??

Answer (score 0):

Append a `.catch((e)=> { console.log(e) });` to your last `then` This will give you the error message which will help you diagnose the error.

Comment: thanks for your answer, did this and still got nothing in the console, i suppose there's no error then right?

Comment: Your code works for me. 
It works from a code pen and from a local python server. Even if the value of Pokemon is an empty string, I was still able to log successfully. I would recommend trying another api.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i Will try with another API.